# Unable to connect remote Mongo DB via meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to connect remote DB from meteor app on my machine using the following code in js file:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.startup(function () {
       var myDatabase = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("http://172.22.77.134:27017");
       MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection("euro2012", { _driver: myDatabase });
     });
   }
```

The following error is thrown:

> Error: EACCES, unlink
>   '/home/garima/my_cool_app/.meteor/local/build-garbage-e7yeel/README'
>       at Object.Future.wait (/home/garima/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
>       at Object.wrapper [as unlink] (/home/garima/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/files.js:1124:24)
>       at Object.files.rm_recursive (/home/garima/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/files.js:262:13)
>       at /home/garima/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/files.js:258:15
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/garima/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>       at Object.files.rm_recursive (/home/garima/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/files.js:256:9)
>       at Object.files.renameDirAlmostAtomically (/home/garima/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/files.js:690:11)

After using sudo I get the following error:

> (STDERR)  W20150225-14:20:26.847(5.5)? (STDERR)
>   /home/garima/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
>   W20150225-14:20:26.847(5.5)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
>   W20150225-14:20:26.848(5.5)? (STDERR)                               ^
>   W20150225-14:20:26.891(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: URL must be in the format
>   mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname W20150225-14:20:26.891(5.5)?
>   (STDERR)     at Error () W20150225-14:20:26.891(5.5)?
>   (STDERR)     at exports.parse
>   (/home/garima/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.0.11.pnwx20++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/url_parser.js:15:11)
>   W20150225-14:20:26.891(5.5)? (STDERR)     at
>   Function.MongoClient.connect
>   (/home/garima/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.0.11.pnwx20++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:164:16)
>   W20150225-14:20:26.891(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Db.connect
>   (/home/garima/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.0.11.pnwx20++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:2035:23)
>   W20150225-14:20:26.891(5.5)? (STDERR)     at new MongoConnection
>   (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:151:1) W20150225-14:20:26.892(5.5)?
>   (STDERR)     at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver
>   (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:1)
>   W20150225-14:20:26.892(5.5)? (STDERR)     at app/my_cool_app.js:26:25
>   W20150225-14:20:26.892(5.5)? (STDERR)     at
>   /home/garima/my_cool_app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:212:5

Comment: The mongodb connection url should be 'mongodb://172.22.77.134:27017/dbname'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more than one issue. The error stopping your app from running is caused by insufficient permissions when you ran your app. Perhaps you ran it with `sudo` once?

To fix that simply make sure you have permissions to all the files in your project.

The other is you're using a `http` url instead of a mongo url when you define `new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver`. A Mongo URI looks something like this

> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

[The full docs on the uri can be found here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Use this URI format instead of the http one to solve this issue (unrelated to the permission issue).

Comment: I have edited the question to add what happens after trying it with sudo

Comment: @garima Yes with sudo it solves the permission problem. After your edit the new error suggests the error is caused by using the incorrect URI format. Please use the format in my answer to solve that issue.